# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code here:

```
var first = orfirst;    
second = eval("document.love.name" +ea).value.toUpperCase();
var names=second;
second = second.replace(r,"");
```

with this code:

```
("document.love.name" +ea).value.toUpperCase();
```

I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name1' of undefined

where:`<input value='' name=name1 onkeyup=checnum(this) type=text size=15>`

because they say that this code id deprecated: `document.love.name` I try to make it like this: `second = eval("document.getElementById('name')" +ea).value.toUpperCase();`.

and then I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Can anyone show me or correct the codes?
THanks in advance.

Comment: If youre using `getElementById()` you have to pass the name (`name1`) and not the type(`name`). You have to create an ID (let's say id1) and after it it should look like this: `getElementById('id1')`. PS: You didn't use quotes on the HTML part to assign the name of the input.

Comment: oh I forgot to tell I already made `name=name1` to `id=name1` so i can use `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 2):

What about adding an ID to the element and using the following code:

```
document.getElementById("name"+ea).value.toUpperCase();
```

Thanks to @Quentin and @Prisoner for spotting that there's no ID at present.

Comment: The element doesn't have an id

Comment: He'd have to add an ID to the input.

Comment: `second = eval("document.getElementById("name"+ea).value.toUpperCase()");` am I doing it right?

Comment: You shouldn't need the eval, and you need to add an ID tag to you input field. So make it read  "name='name 1' id='name 1'"